# Update another table after insert using a trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm currently creating some sort of inventory system.

I have `tbl1` where in I save the items. In `tbl1`, I have column `qty` or the available stock left.

tbl1:

```
id product  qty
1  mouse    10
2  keyboard 15
3  monitor  8
```

I also have the table `tbl2` where in I save all the transaction in issuing items. In this table there is `issued_qty`.

tbl2

```
id requested_by product  issued_qty
1  john         mouse    2
```

My problem is how can I INSERT a row into `tbl2` at the same time UPDATE the `tbl1.qty (tbl1.qty - tbl2.issued_qty)`.

for example:
when I insert record in `tbl2` in requested_by, product and qty_issued, I want the `tbl1` to be automatically updated. since we issue 2 (qty) of mouse to John. the record of mouse in tbl1, should be automatically less to the no. of issued quantity in `tbl2`

My idea is to use `TRIGGER`

but unfortunately I have no success.. can you please help me with this one..

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're not expecting huge amounts of data use a view or a stored procedure to calculate on the fly and return actual quantity. It may save you a lot of headache in the long run.

Your view (actually views) might look like

```sql
CREATE VIEW vw_table2_sum AS
SELECT product, SUM(issued_qty) qty
  FROM Table2
 GROUP BY product;

CREATE VIEW vw_table1 AS
SELECT t.id, t.product, t.qty - COALESCE(v.qty, 0) qty
  FROM Table1 t LEFT JOIN vw_table2_sum v
    ON t.product = v.product;
```

When we do

```
SELECT * FROM vw_table1;
```

will get

```
| ID |  PRODUCT | QTY |
-----------------------
|  1 |    mouse |   8 | -- the quantity is current
|  2 | keyboard |  15 |
|  3 |  monitor |   8 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0f4c0/1)** demo

Now if you for some reason want to manage your inventory quantity with a trigger it might look like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ai_table2
AFTER INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE Table1
     SET qty = qty - NEW.issued_qty
   WHERE product = NEW.product;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f57ca/1)** demo

Comment: wow, thanks a lot Sir peterm. This is what i'm looking for for a week now.